# Using GradleBuild , how to specify individual task to execute from tasks list

Tags: gradle

I've two gradle files :

**build.gradle**

```
apply from :'other.gradle'

task hiHelloWrapper(type: GradleBuild) {
    buildFile = 'other.gradle'
    tasks = ['hi','hello']
}
```

**other.gradle**

```
task hello<<{
    println 'hello from other'

}

task hi<<{
    println 'hi from other'

}
```

Now, when I execute

```
>gradle hiHelloWrapper
```

it results in both tasks **hi** and **hello** being executed and they are executed in their relative order in **tasks** list .

Is there any way that I can execute selectively one of them without creating another task which includes only one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood you just need to run:

```
gradle hi
```

or

```
gradle hello
```

All tasks from `other.gradle` are *imported* to build gradle and can be used out of the box.

Comment: Thanks ! Also , it seems that it is not required to make a task of type GradleBuild to create a task in build.gradle which depends on tasks from other.gradle.